# Palíndromo em Java

Tags: java

Alguém poderia me ajudar com esse exercício me explicando?

Ex: Write a function that checks if a given word is a palindrome. Character case should be ignored.
For example, isPalindrome("Deleveled") should return true as character case should be ignored, resulting in "deleveled", which is a palindrome since it reads the same backward and foward.

```
public class Palindrome {
    public static boolean isPalindrome(String word) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Waiting to be implemented.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Palindrome.isPalindrome("Deleveled"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Primeiro, você deve entender a definição de um palíndromo. Depois, pense como você vai verificar se a palavra é um palíndromo ou não. Se, após escrever o seu código, você ainda não estiver conseguindo, coloque o que você tentou na sua pergunta.

Comment: Eu não entendo pq tem declaração na linha do public static

Comment: Que declaração?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

game-extreme, vou tentar te ajudar sem dar a resposta pronta, afinal é um exercício e é vc quem tem que resolve-lo, ok?

vejo que vc tem dificuldades em 2 coisas: a lógica e a liguagem.

Partindo do pressuposto que vc já sabe oque é um palíndromo (a grosso modo, a sequencia dos caracteres é a mesma nas duas direções, por ex: 1234321).

Primeiro sugiro que vc desenhe a solução, faça tipo um algorítimo, por exemplo:

- criar um método que retorne a palavra de trás pra frente (pesquise na API do StringUtils, ou outra qualquer, ou melhor ainda, faça o seu próprio pra treinar...)
- verifique se a palavra recebida é igual ao retorno do método que inverte a palavra.
- retornar o resultado da comparação

Depois que vc fizer o desenho da solução, vá por partes, transcrevendo isso pra Java. Como o G. Otani P. falou, quando vc tentar fazer e tiver uma duvida específica, aí sim vc faz uma pergunta mais direcionada.

Boa sorte.